# Object list within an object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created  an object that contains an Arraylist and that Arraylist contains objects. My question is, how do i point to the objects in the Arraylist?

the original Object contains:
some attributes,
list = new arraylist

The List contains:
14 objects of similar data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a fairly simple task, but because you did not give me your exact code, I am just going to *assume*.

Let's say this is the class of the object that you were talking about

```
public class ClassA {
    public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); //I guess integers are "similar data"
}
```

Now you have that object, called `obj`

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA ();
```

You can just access the array list by doing this

```
obj.list
```

For example you can add an item to the array list like this:

```
obj.list.add(10);
```

And you can retrieve the first item

```
obj.list.get(0);
```

Easy!

If you think you understand little of the above, I'll explain. If you think you understand it completely, you can just accept the answer and go.

Almost every class declare *members*. And so does your class, `ClassA`. Any accessible member can be accessed using `.`. We call it *the dot operator*.

And what is an accessible member?

Different *access modifiers* provide different accessibility, read this to find out more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html In the above example, `list` is a member, and it is declared `public` This means that it is accessible *everywhere*.

This is why you can access it using `.`.

Actually, I think you must have used this technique before! When you call

```
System.out.println ("Hello World");
```

You use the dot to access members!

In the `System` class, there is a member called `out`. `out` is of type `PrintStream`. In `PrintStream` class, there is another member called `println`! See? that's how Java works.

If you still don't understand, read this part again. If you understand, please click that green tick to accept the answer.